# DataGrid Row Header WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a populated DataTable (xDataTable) with 7 defined columns - the first column I want to use as my RowHeader.

I also have a DataGrid:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridX" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="0" 
           CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" />
```

I then set the DataContext of my DataGrid:

```
DataGridX.DataContext = xDataTable;
```

This all works - but how can I set the first column of my DataGrid as a RowHeader?

Comment: is it MVVM or code-behind?

Comment: you are auto Generating columns?

Comment: @KyloRen my columns are hard coded using .Columns.Add().

Comment: @JoelH then don't add that column in datagrid and bind that column to row header.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Use the below style (usual case):**

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=Columns[0].Header,Mode=OneTime}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

**If we want separate RowHeader for separate Row then use:**

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsRowSelected}" />
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Content}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Just change the above binding as required.

If the first column is:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Content}" Header="Content"/>
```

then remove this column and use this binding for the Header.

Comment: Even with the second example, the row header is always equal to the name of the first column. Maybe I didn't fully articulate my answer - I am after the value in the first column being the Row Header.

Comment: ok i get it. If you are not autogenerating columns then just bind the header with that column name(as now in my 2nd example) and remove Datagrid column from column definition. @JoelH that should work

Comment: that works - my first column is now the row header. However, then the first column is displayed again as another column - can I prevent this?

Comment: Yes. you don't need to add that column in the grid. while doing Columns.Add().

Answer (score 0):

you can set any headers whatever you want. Just add your columns like that:

```
 DataTable.Columns.Add("I am a Column Header!:)");
```

**Let' see MVVM example:**

```
public class YourViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        PopulateDataTable();
    }

    private void PopulateDataTable()
    {
        var _ds = new DataSet("Test");
        employeeDataTable = new DataTable();
        employeeDataTable = _ds.Tables.Add("DT");
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {                
            //you can set any Header in the following line
            employeeDataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var theRow = employeeDataTable.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                theRow[j] = "a";                    
            }
            employeeDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow);
        }
    }

     private DataTable employeeDataTable;

     public DataTable EmployeeDataTable
     {
        get { return employeeDataTable; }
        set
        {
            employeeDataTable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeDataTable");
        }
     }
}
```

Your XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeDataTable}" />
```

**Update:**

**Let's see code-behind example:**

Your XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"/>
```

Your code-behind:

```
//constructor of the Window
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PopulateDataGrid();
}

DataTable employeeDataTable = new DataTable();


private void PopulateDataGrid()
{
   var _ds = new DataSet("Test");

   employeeDataTable = _ds.Tables.Add("DT");
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//create columns
   {   
        employeeDataTable.Columns.Add("I am a column!:)");
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)//fill data to rows
   {
       var theRow = employeeDataTable.NewRow();
       for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
       {
          if (j % 2 == 0)                    
              theRow[j] = "a";  
          else                  
              theRow[j] = "b";
       }
       employeeDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow);
   }
   dataGrid.ItemsSource = employeeDataTable.AsDataView();
}
```