# How to populate a class to a grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class `InfoField` containing members of various types.  I want to bind an `ObservableCollection<InfoField>` property to some sort of WPF controller.

- The class members are listed horizontally and all collection elements are listed vertically.
- Both columns and rows have headers.
- I can apply different data templates for the various data types.
- I can press the column headers (e.g. ShowRpm) to select all the checkboxes under it.

I've been testing with `ListView`, but I'm not sure that's the right way to go.  From what I can see, I'll have trouble getting points two and four to work using `ListView`.  Anybody got a good idea on which control to use for this?

```
          ShowRpm    ShowCurrent  ShowTemperature  Direction
Motor1   (checkbox)  (checkbox)   (checkbox)       (combobox)
Motor2   (checkbox)  (checkbox)   (checkbox)       (combobox)
Motor3   (checkbox)  (checkbox)   (checkbox)       (combobox)
 ...
MotorN   (checkbox)  (checkbox)   (checkbox)       (combobox)
```

C#:

```
public class InfoField {
    public bool ShowRpm { get; set; }
    public bool ShowCurrent { get; set; }
    public bool ShowTemperature { get; set; }
    public Direction Direction { get; set; }
}

public enum Direction {
    Horizontal,
    Vertical
}
```

Comment: I'd consider using a `DataGridView`. You may have to do a little customization to satisfy all of you points, but it should be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use a DataGrid. With some customization you should be able to statisy all your options. This is a starting point you can use

```
//Collection for the datagrid
public ObservableCollection<InfoField> infoFieldData;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    infoFieldData = new ObservableCollection<InfoField>();

    InfoField info1 = new InfoField();
    InfoField info2 = new InfoField();

    infoFieldData.Add(info1);
    infoFieldData.Add(info2);

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = infoFieldData;
    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}



public class InfoField
{
    public bool ShowRpm { get; set; }
    public bool ShowCurrent { get; set; }
    public bool ShowTemperature { get; set; }
    public Direction Direction { get; set; }
}

public enum Direction
{
    Horizontal,
    Vertical
}
```

The DataGrid XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" CanUserAddRows="False"/>
```

For point 2 of having row headers there's this question [DataGrid Row Header WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288097/datagrid-row-header-wpf)

For the point 4 there's this [How do I capture “Click” events on a DataGrid column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895803/how-do-i-capture-click-events-on-a-datagrid-column-headers)